# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker

I have recently started working on docker and I'm periodically getting this message:

```
root@yash:/home/yashvardhan# docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: "Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'." And what is the answer to this, rather important, question?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your user doesn't have privileges to run Docker. Try using:

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: He is using "root". "root" does not need privileges.

Comment: yes you are right, it escaped me that, when you've installed Docker you have also created a user or not? You could try using that user or you could create a new user which you will have to add to the *docker* group @Yuushi